# NSMutableArray of NSMutableArrays

Tags: objective-c, arrays, pointers, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

I want to create an NSMutableArray of NSMutableArrays.  Below is the psuedo code:

```
NSMutableArray *mapcoords = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
NSMutableArray *clustercoords = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

while (!FINISHED)
{
   for(int j = 1;j <= 4;j++)
    {
       x = arc4random_uniform(45);
       [mapcoords addobject:[NSNumber numberWitInt:x]];

    }

    [clustercoords addobject:mapcoords];
    [mapcoords removeAllObjects];
}
```

When I inspect the "clustercoords" array at the end of the loop, all of the objects contain the same values.  I figured this must be because I am pointing to the same object (mapcoords) every time I add it to clustercoords.

I assume that I would need a different several different "mapcoords" arrays so that the objects in mapccords are unique.  Is this the correct assumption?  Is there another alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. Move the declaration and creation of `mapcoords` inside the `while` loop.

```
NSMutableArray *clustercoords = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

while (!FINISHED) {
    NSMutableArray *mapcoords = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 
    for(int j = 1; j <= 4; j++) {
       u_int32_t x = arc4random_uniform(45);
       [mapcoords addObject:@(x)];
    }

    [clustercoords addObject:mapcoords];
}
```

Comment: It worked perfectly.  Thanks, maddy!  But can you explain to me why this solution worked.  Is it that I was creating a new unique instance of the name "mapcoords" each time at a different memory location?

Comment: No. In your code you kept reusing the same mutable array referenced by the `mapcoords` variable. You added 4 numbers, add a reference to `mapcoords` into the `clustercoords` array. Then you removed the 4 numbers and added 4 new numbers. You then added another reference to `mapcoords` into the `clustercoords` array. Repeat over and over. In the end you had X number of references to the one `mapcoords` array in `clustercoords` and the one `mapcoords` was either empty or had the last set of 4 numbers in it depending on when you exited the while loop.